Removing a sphere from an arrayed body
I hope that somebody can help, I am trying to remove a sphere from a body that is created from an array along a curve. When I try and run a boolean modifier to remove the sphere, the array body doesn't get cut how I would expect it to and it seems to just remove sections of the arrayed body.
I've tried using the merge feature in the array modifier but that doesn't seem to help.
If anyone would be able to give me some pointers then that would be great! I am pressuming it's something to do with the base model that I have been given to work with but some advice would be greatly appreciated.
I've attached a simplified version of the file here: https://easyupload.io/zdl6qy.



(Using Blender 3.6.8)
Because of the "snake" open ends, the Hole Tolerant Solver Options should be activated for the Boolean modifier:


That's great, thank you so much! I've managed to get it to work on the sample file, now I just need to leave my computer alone for a week while it works out the full version.
Thanks again :)
